# How to get Truck restrictions of an area in Here Maps API?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

There is this [truck restrictions map](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/map-tile/map-tile-truck) in the Here website.

But this only shows an image which is not of much use. Is there any way to get the info in a proper format?

Answer (score 0):

Please try our Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets product. The HERE Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets is a REST API that allows you to use HERE core map data that is not accessible through other HERE APIs, including tiles, data records and attributes.

For truck related, we have
TRUCK_RESTR_FC1...5(Truck restriction info for routing) and TRUCK_SPEED_LIMITS_FC1...5 (Truck speed limit info) layers to providing truck restriction and speed limit attributes.

For example, to get one particular tile with truck restrictions, you can use below API call
https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tile.json?layer=TRUCK_RESTR_FC3&level=11
&tilex=2146&tiley=1594&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}

Please check the developer documentation [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have couple of immediate doubts on this: 

1 - Where can I get level, tilex & tiley for a particular area? In the example in this link there are zoom, column & row. Not sure if they correspond to level, tilex & tiley. 

2 - How can I match the response to particular roads? The response has LINK_IDS but no other information that can help me identify for which road these jsons correspond to. Thanks

Comment: Regarding Q1: please check here on how to get level, tileX, tileY for a region
https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/example-tile.html. Regarding Q2: if you know the level, tileX, tileY, basically you can get many information from different layers for the same tile. For example, you can request ROAD_NAME_FC3 to get the road names. By matching the link id, you should be able to get the information you want.

Comment: Thanks. 
I get road names like: "GERBNKalbacher Hauptstraße\u001E\u001EGERY\"ka:l|%ba|x6 \"haUpt|%Stra:|s@\u001DGERBNL3003\u001E\u001EGERN\"?El %draI|taU|z=nt|\"draI;GERN\"lant|Stra:|s@ \"draI|sIC \"nUl \"draI;GERY\"?El \"draI|sIC \"nUI \"draI;GERN\"lant|Stra:|s@ %draI|taU|z=nt|\"draI"

What are the extra characters and how to convert to actual road names?

Comment: Also I don't get response of restrictions e.g. in this case: https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tile.json?layer=TRUCK_RESTR_FC3&level=11&tilex=2048&tiley=1615&apiKey=<MyKey> all I get is this: {"Rows":[]}

Comment: LINK_ID in ROAD_NAME and in TRUCK_RESTRICTION are different and in different format! How can I truly match the truck restriction to actual roads in that case?

Comment: link found to be broken. Anyone have any ideas?